# How can you get 6 gems in a row in Bejeweled Twist?

Tags: bejeweled-twist

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bejeweled_Twist a supernova gem is created when six or more gems are matched in a line. How is that possible? Wouldn't you have to already have three in a line:

```
XXXAXX
AAXAAA
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have to set up a cascade to be able to get longer lines of gems.  You will not be able to do this in a single move.  (Disclaimer: I don't have this version of the Bejeweled but the concept is the same in any game like this)

Here's one such cascade you can make which should be relatively easy to set up.

Try to get your gems in this pattern:

```
  AA
  BB
  CC C
  BB
AABBAA
```

Then to finish it off, just move gem C in place to start the cascade.

Getting off longer lines are often difficult to set up.  Here's another variation for a 7/8 gem line.

```
  A  A
  B  B
 CCD DD
  BC B
AABAABAA
```

Then rotate C and D in place to set off the cascade.

You'll get the idea.

Comment: Your last example confuses me.  Shouldn't it be CCDCDD on one line?

Comment: @JasonBerkan: Looking at videos of this game, they are rotated (twisted) into place, not swapped.

Comment: Ah - didn't notice that the question was not referring to blitz.  Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a pattern that looks like this:

```
 ..AA..
 ..BC..
 ..CC..  
 AABBAA
```

Twist C and B so that they are both matched in one cascade; one cascade later, you'll have your supernova.

Comment: How many twists are you making? You'll need more than one to cause a match.